# jquery selected dropdown return true or false

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu, selected

I have a dropdown and I want to use jquery to see if the option selected has the selected field in it `<option id="id" class="class" selected >Option</option>` is there a method in jquery that will do this to return true or false depending on what it is

Comment: since the option has an id you can `$('#id').is(':selected')`

Comment: Expand your question please...

Comment: Arun P Johny that is exactly what I wanted may you please write this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

ou can use jQuery to inspect everything on the selected item.

```
// get the selected item 

// note: this is getting the parent 'select' element first and then finding 
//       the selected option within the selects child elements

var selectedOption = $('select').find('option:selected');

// you could also use a selector to find a specific select within the page, e.g.,
var select = $('select.my-select'); // this will find a select with a class attribute of 'my-select'

// get the text from it
var text = selectedOption.text();

// get the html from it
var html = selectedOption.html();

// get an attribute from it
var classNames = selectedOption.attr('class');
var id = selectedOption.attr('id');
```